# How does the Android Lockscreen get the Coverart?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen

I know that I need to use a broadcast Receiver to get the currently playing song.
But how do I Get the cover art of this explicit song? On the lockscreen it also works with Spotify or Google Music .. so no local Files are involved?

I am not able to  find any clues on the extras of my receiving intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock screen utilizes a [RemoteController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.html), which allows you to listen to any apps that publish music controls via a [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html).

Note that `RemoteController` was only made public in Android 4.4 and is not available prior to that. Unfortunately, there is no standardized broadcasts that fulfill this same role.

Comment: Thank you! Too bad. Then I will try to download the coverart on the fly.